# In Unity, is there a way to Set a new MeshRenderer?

Tags: unity, c#, game-component

Here is what I want to do in Unity for a given `GameObject go = new GameObject()`. I want to create a `MeshRenderer`, change its properties and only in the end set it as the component of `go`. For instance:

```
MeshRenderer newmeshrenderer;
(...) //do stuff with newmeshrenderer
go.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>() = newmeshrenderer;
(or)
go.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>(newmeshrenderer);
```

But both way fail. What is the correct way of setting a MeshRenderer previously created to be the MeshRenderer of an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd do this in the opposite order. Rather than:

1. Create
2. Modify
3. Attach to GameObject (there's no way provided to do this)

the order is:

1. Create and attach to GameObject (one fused step)
2. Modify

Like so:

```
GameObject go = new GameObject();
MeshRenderer newmeshrenderer = go.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
// Do stuff with newmeshrenderer, eg...
newmeshrenderer.sharedMaterial = theAwesomeMaterial;
newmeshrenderer.shadowCastingMode = ShadowCastingMode.off;
// etc.
```

The MeshRenderer doesn't actually do anything until the script finishes and the next frame is rendered, so there's no harm in configuring it in-place like this.

If you want to apply a MeshRenderer with identical settings to many GameObjects, the best way is to create a convenience method for yourself:

```
void AddAndConfigureMeshRenderer(GameObject recipient)
{
    MeshRenderer mr = recipient.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    // Configure mr the way you want it...
    mr.sharedMaterial = theAwesomeMaterial;
    //etc..
}
```

Then you can call this repeatedly, passing each GameObject you want to attach this custom MeshRenderer to. You could also add parameters if you want to be able to do this with multiple distinct MeshRenderer configurations.

Comment: Thanks! I And it's obvious... I knew it had to be simple and that my tiredness should have been preventing me from seeing the obvious. Anyway, I specially like the convenience method. Made my code much cleaner

Answer (score 2):

It should work like the example on the Scripting API for AddComponent http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html

```
MeshRenderer mr = gameObject.AddComponent("MeshRenderer");
(...) //do stuff with mr
```